# Raspberry Pi: Filesystem writes files, but after reboot the old data is back

Tags: 14.04, arm, raspberrypi

Okay this is a really weird problem occurring on two raspberry pi systems with their respective 8GB SD memory cards:

Simple example:
When I write files to the disk, it looks like the files are written.
I can edit a file `vim test.dat`, enter text into it, save.
ll will list the file.
cat will show the contents of the file.
After a reboot the file will be gone.

So what I think is happening is that ubuntu writes the files to ubuntu's disk cache but it doesn't commit the files to disk. The userspace programs can continue reading the files and using them, but the cache returns the directory listings and file contents from ram, and not from the disk. Because after a reboot the disk has none of the new data.

Another example:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=testfile.dat bs=1M count=1000
```

It creates a file with 1GB size.
ll lists the file.
df -h shows that 1GB more has been used by the data on disk.
But after a reboot the file is gone and df -h shows the old available space.

Fun fact: I know the SD card's max writing speed is 9MB/sec, which is what I get when I dd the disk image onto it using my laptop. But running this dd command on the SD card in the raspberry, dd reports the write speed as 110MB/sec. Impossible. This is why I think the operating system is just writing to RAM and not committing to disk.

Third example:
I have a script that edits a file named interfaces, and then copies it, as root, over the /etc/network/interfaces file, to change the IP of the device. Then the script reboots.

```
#!/bin/bash
cp /var/project/scripts/interfaces /etc/network/interfaces
/sbin/reboot
```

After the reboot, the device is still on its old IP address... Weird...

Fourth example:
The raspberry runs a percona database.  I have a table that contains 186 entries.  I truncate the table.  Look at the data using the php code and also using webmin - the table is empty like it should be.  After a reboot the data is back.  Really... 186 entries.  This is freaking me out.

I can be completely wrong.  Any ideas?

I have been working on this ubuntu installation and making periodic backups by cloning the disk image after every major sofware update.  I have been noticing strange things (like the IP not changing after running my script) but I did not realise this problem until today, it seems like all the cloned disk images I have exhibit this issue. It must have worked fine up to a point and then something went wrong with ubuntu on the pi...

Question:  What can I do to get ubuntu to write to the SD card?

Comment: When I realised the files are not written to the SD card, the first thing I suspected was that the SD card is faulty.  So I switched on another raspberry running an older version of the ubuntu installation on its own SD card and it exhibited exactly the same issue!

Comment: Where did you get the installer from for Ubuntu? I've seen before on my Beaglebone that some of the available images are booted as a RAM filesystem, and hence no changes are ever permanent. Are you able to make other changes? If you install something with `apt-get`, does that persist over a reboot?

Comment: Installed from https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi.I have been working on this installation for over a year.  Installed Percona database, php, cakephp, a bluetooth stack, nodejs, apache, hostapd, etc etc.  All of the installs and data updates worked perfectly over all that time. But at some stage it stopped writing to disk

Comment: If I can't fix the file write issue, I suppose my next step is to use chef to install from scratch, to create a reproducible stable install. But considering all the components that has gone into this, you can understand that will be a lot of work.

Comment: Could apparmor be causing this issue?

Comment: I'm really not sure, I'm afraid. It wouldn't be AppArmor, if it was then nothing would be allowed to be written at all.

Comment: Today, I found a 3-month old SD-card/device that writes to disk properly.  I re-did all the missing dev work on it and am now cloning it to the SD card on the one device that exhibited this strange write-missing behaviour. Will post updates as I know more.

Comment: What is the filesystem you use? I have similar problems on Raspbian Wheezy on a FAT32 partition of my SD card.. Also not SD card related.

Answer (score 2):

What seemed to help me was using the sync command:

```
sync
```

From the help:

> Force changed blocks to disk, update the super block.

It flushes the filesystem buffers in other words.
However I would expect that when you do a proper `sudo reboot` unlike me, this would be no issue and hence the sync might not work for you..

I was having similar issues with a raspbian wheezy install.
It has an ext4 partition containing the filesystem which is read-only. And a small read-write partition with FAT32 containing some configfiles. When I changed a config file and then pulled the power plug to restart the changes were not persistent. (be advised: without a read-only Pi, pulling the power plug would not be a smart thing to do anyway)

Answer (score 2):

I have same problem with Samsung EVO 18G MicroSD card. Many people discussed this issue in raspberry forum here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=21330#p992573

Most likely is SD Card corrupted.

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered exactly same problem. I solved this problem by doing following steps:

- **STEP 1:** Observe value that specified after `root=PARTUUID=` from `/boot/cmdline.txt`:

  ```
  cat /boot/cmdline
  ```

  In my case, I found something like `093bedcc-02`:

  ```
  boot=overlay console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=093bedcc-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait
  ```
- **STEP 2:** Find PATH with the specified value of `root=PARTUUID=` from the previous step with `lsblk` (for more detail read `man lsblk` to format the output):

  ```
  lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,LABEL,UUID,PARTUUID,MOUNTPOINT,PATH
  ```

  In my case, I got something like:

  ```
  NAME        FSTYPE LABEL  UUID                                 PARTUUID                             MOUNTPOINT PATH
  mmcblk0                                                                                                        /dev/mmcblk0
  ├─mmcblk0p1 vfat   boot   BC50-2AE4                            093bedcc-01                          /boot      /dev/mmcblk0p1
  └─mmcblk0p2 ext4   rootfs 9b87f948-9dc3-49e7-94fc-309bfabb1ac4 093bedcc-02                          /          /dev/mmcblk0p2
  ```

  In my case, I got the **PATH** value as `/dev/mmcblk0p2`.
- **STEP 3:** Now replace `root=PARTUUID=` with its PATH vale (in my case, `/dev/mmcblk0p2`) by prepending `root=`:

  ```
  root=/dev/mmcblk0p2
  ```
- **STEP 4:** Finally reboot the system with following command:

  ```
  sudo reboot
  ```

Comment: Could you explain what you are doing, and how it solves the problem? I'm trying to understand your solution.

Comment: @MartinFürholz, I was trying to edit a file on the SD card of my RPi. I saved a file into the SD card after editing the file. The RPi kept the changes of that fille unless the system is rebooted. For some reason, the changes were gone. I don't know whether the changes are saved in RAM/cache memory.

However, I have alter the `root` partition parameter `root=PARTUUID=093bedcc-02` with `root=/dev/mmcblk0p2` and have rebooted the system. The system worked fine afterward.